# how to redirect user to settings page?

Tags: javascript, push-notification, notifications

Let's say I am writing an app which uses push notifications.

I want an user to redirect to settings|notifications page of the browser so that he can enable it.

How do i redirect them to that page via Javascript for any browser?

Comment: Is there any issue in using window.location.href = "settings page url" ?

Comment: i think all browsers will have different page url right? so i should check which browser it is ?

Comment: "window" is common javascript object have support of all its property across all the modern browser.

Comment: i know that. i meant "settings page url"

Comment: I misunderstood with custom setting.